# android studio - set gradlew/gradle jdk

Tags: android, intellij-idea, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, gradlew

OS: OSX 10.9.2
build tool: gradle
platform: android
I've recently installed jdk 8 which i use for some side projects. i have 1.6, 1.7 and 1.8 installed at the same time.

The issue that i'm having is when building android projects, in android studio using gradlew its using jdk 8, instead of using the jdk that i've set for the project. This causes issues as one of the gradle plugins i'm using (new relic agent) does not yet support java 8.

I dont know how android studio decides what jdk to use for gradle, but it should use the same as the jdk you set for you project, otherwise what is the point in asking me to set one?

So my question is this. How can i set what jdk to use for gradlew in android studio, or in intellij in general as i'm sure this will affect other projects too

Comment: Where, exactly, are you setting it for the project?

Comment: file > projct structure > jdk location